# Connection pool have hundreds of idle connections

Tags: java, database, datacontext

I have these setting in my context file for the applications I have.

I'm seeing connection pools have hundreds of idle connections wasting DB resources.

I'm trying to figure out what  I need to have in my context to avoid the connection pool issue:

```
   type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    maxActive="10" 
    initialSize="0"
    maxAge="1800"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    testOnReturn="false"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
    validationInterval="30000"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    logAbandoned="true"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="18000"
    jmxEnabled="true"
    fairQueue="true"
    jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
```

beside the pool connection the application will throw this error: ((ORA-12516 ))

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
```

ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack

```
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:275) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
```

Comment: Besides see the connections is this causing any actual problems?  And what is your app server?  I'm guessing you're using and Oracle DB based on the validation query.

Comment: was missing the whole block of the code.

Comment: also the application will throw an error on the start up (ORA-12516 )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742794/ora-12516-tnslistener-could-not-find-available-handler

Comment: Thank you. but I was trying to find a client solution for my config